# Simplify PHP code and Regex

Tags: php, regex

I could use some help simplifying the following code that includes a regex statement. I am simply trying to get the integers from all possible substrings contained in a larger text and then push those integers onto an array. I know I should not have to use split, but I forget how to do do it with regex.

```
    preg_match_all('/bar:foo\(?[0-9]*\);/', $in , $tag);
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($tag[0]); $i++) {
        $parts = explode("(", $tag[0][$i]);           
        $parts2 = explode(")", $parts[1]);
        array_push($myArr, $parts2[0]);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Actually, you might not need to use `preg_split`, but you can already improve it by modifying your current pattern:

```
$numbers = preg_match_all('/bar:foo\(?([0-9]*)\);/', $in , $matches) 
           ? array_map('intval', $matches[1])
           : array();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
preg_match_all('/bar:foo\(?([0-9]*)\);/', $in , $tags);
print_r($tags);
```